# Neither fwrite nor write work in my C++ program

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm writing a c++ program for my school project which involves lots of binary files. My problem is that whenever the compiler encounters a write statement (by this I mean writing data from an object of a class to a binary file using fstream::write), execution stops and I get an abnormal termination message. I'm sure the 'write' statement is the problem because every statement before it gets executed, while the next statements do not. The problem seemed to have been solved when I used fwrite instead, but then I discovered that data was not actually being written into the file. I've tried writing the object into the file in another function or in methods using 'this' pointer, but the computer doesn't seem to accept any of it.

The program was working just fine until a few days ago, but seemingly out of the blue, it's stopped working. I can't attach the source code because the problem is spread throughout the program, which is 5000+ lines long. However, here's a sample of what causes problems:

```
bottle b; //bottle is a class
fstream file ("Bottle.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);
file.write ((char*)&b,sizeof(b));
```

As an alternate, I've also tried

```
FILE*fptr=fopen ("Bottle.dat","w");
fwrite (&b, sizeof(b), 1, fptr);
```

The former results in abnormal termination, the latter does not work. There are no error messages during compilation. Can anybody help me? I'm a total newbie at programming, though (still in high school), so please try to keep it  simple. Thanks!

EDIT: Maybe this will work as better example.

```
class irrigation
{   int n,i,itime[20],t[20];
    float amt[20],water[20];
protected:
    float irr;
public:
    float getirr()
    {   return irr;
    }
    void irrigate();
};

void irrigate_calc()
{   fstream file ("Irrigate.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
    irrigation i;
    file.read ((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    file.close();
    i.irrigate();
    fstream file1 ("Irrigate.dat",ios::out|ios::binary);
    file1.write ((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    file1.close();
}
```

As far as I can tell, the problem arises when I open a file for reading, close it again and then open it for writing. Of course, I did try directly opening the file in ios::in, ios::out and ios::ate mode together, but that messed things up, big time.

EDIT 2: Another issue the same program is facing is that some normal cout statements intermittently spew out garbage: lots of special characters and little bits from other, totally unrelated cout statements. Any particular reason this is happening?

Comment: That would only work if `bottle` is a _POD_ type. How is `bottle` defined?

Comment: Oh, really? Bottle is definitely not a POD: it has private and protected data members as well as public member functions. So I can't use fwrite then?

Comment: You can, but you wont get anything meaningful from it... You shouldn't be getting a crash though

Comment: I get a crash when I use fstream::write. I don't really know all that much about fwrite; I found out about it online as an alternative to fstream::write. I wasn't sure if I was using it correctly.

Comment: For your particular use case those should be the same. `fstream` wraps all the _C_ file related functionality, like `fopen` and `fwrite`

Comment: Can you provide a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `I can't attach the source code because <excuse>` _Always_ means you didn't create a _testcase_ during your debugging, which means you should not be here asking yet. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the response :)
I hope the example I've given now better illustrates the problem.
And I have tried a couple of test cases, actually (albeit simple ones). I don't know, though. This thing is eating at me. I've been working on the program since last summer!

Comment: In the fopen case, be sure to check whether or not fopen() returned NULL and do something appropriate... if you just blindly call fwrite() afterwards, then your program will crash if the output file could not be opened for some reason (e.g. when the current directory doesn't have write permission) ... because fwrite() would try to dereference the NULL fptr.

Comment: Turns out fopen() did return NULL. I tried using perror() to determine what the problem was, and I found that there wasn't enough memory. So I'm deleting a few functions and deallocating memory space as I go on. Thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since your object is not `POD`, in a simple way, you can try to write out all of its members. For instance,

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    // Simple constructor
    B(int mem1, char mem2) : member1(mem1), member2(mem2) {}

    // Have some methods here
    bool write() const {
      fstream file("Bottle.dat", ios::out|ios::binary);
      if(!file.is_open())
        return false;
      file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&member1), sizeof(int));
      file.write(&member2, sizeof(char));
      file.close();
      return true;
    }

private:
    int member1;
    char member2;
};

int main()
{
  B sample(52, 'c');
  sample.write();
  return 0;
}
```

Now you can call `yourobj.write()` and it can write out to `Bottle.dat`. You can write out/encode your data in anyway you wish. But this is a simple direct output. Your first 4 bytes (well, `sizeof(int)` bytes) will be `member1` and your next byte is `member2`. Thus, you can easily read in this format if you would like as well.

**EDIT**

I have updated my code to make it a compilable sample. You can observe the output file with a hex editor to verify everything is correct. You should be able (in any editor) to be able to visibly see the `char` ('c') which corresponds to `member2`. If you open this in a hex editor, you will see that the first 4-bytes are equal to the number `0x34`. Depending on the endianess of your machine, it may look like `00000034` or `34000000` this is decimal `52` which is what we expect based on my sample code.

Comment: This looks quite promising. But when I compile, I'm now getting lots of errors. My directory doesn't seem to include stdbool.h, so I changed the bool return type to int, false to 0 and true to 1. Also, it said that there were not enough parameters in file.open(), so I made a change. My code now reads: fstream file; if (!file.open ("Bottle.dat",ios::out)) ... But then it says that the if statement is not an allowed type. Also, for the file.write parts, it says that it could not find a match for ostream::write with the given parameter list. Am I possibly missing a header file?

Comment: @Galena Sorry - the example was not necessarily compilable. I have updated it so you can copy/paste this code and see its execution.

Comment: You would read the file in as binary. You would read `sizeof(int)` number of bytes and cast that to an `int`. That said, if you're dealing with binary, you'll also want a way to check for endianess of your machine vs endianess of the file for how to interpret those 4 bytes you read in.